# Azure Blob Storage: Is it possible to search using Blob Index Tags inside a specific virtual folder (path)?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I am using `FindBlobsByTags` to retrieve the necessary blobs. The problem is that this will search through entire blob container. But I just need to search through a specific folder.

**Question:** Is there a way to search through a specific folder to retrieve the necessary blobs using Blob Tags?

**Use Case**

Here is my container structure, You can see that there is lot of folders. But at a point of time, I need to search through a particular path only (Eg. @Container/2001/A).

[image]

**Solution Tried:**

1. Having Folder Name in Tag and using that tag to filter out the result to the specific folder.

   - Disadvantages:

     1. Using multi tag query is not optimized in Blob Storage
     2. Increases the cost of Blob Indexing

Answer (score 0):

Vijay, I doubt the current SDK supports this feature. FindBlobsByTags returns only a reactive Publisher emitting the blobs in this account whose tags match the query expression. A feature to report at feedback.azure.com so that the MS Azure product team can add it to their feature list.

- Ravi Kanth

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @SumanthMarigowda-MSFT I have updated the post with the use case